# Why won't Visual Studio break on this unhandled exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, debugging

When submitting a form, a Yellow Screen of Death appeared even while in Debug mode in Visual Studio. The problem I had is solved, it was a missing resource value, but I'm interested in why I'm not able to break on the exception.

I tried the following, but nothing changed the situation:

- Stepping through the code.
- Changing the `Debug -> Exceptions` settings.
- Checking `Enable .NET Framework source stepping` and `Enable source server support`.

How can such an exception be caught, or why is it not possible to catch it?

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(String value) +52015
   System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__1.MoveNext() +135
   System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__5.MoveNext() +318
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1367
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +449
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +117
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: Sounds like the model, a parameter in the model or another parameter that you are passing back to your controller has a null value.  VS is not breaking on the exception because it is happening inside of the MVC core (ModelBinding).

Comment: @Tommy Isn't the third thing I tried supposed to let me step into the MVC code?

Comment: Not if you don't have the .pdb files for System.Web.Mvc loaded on your machine/project.  The debugger has to have those .pdb files to step into compiled source.

Comment: @Tommy you put me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: How did you fix this exception?

Comment: @BohdanKuts one of the resx files was missing an entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to break on this exception, because Microsoft's public Symbol Server does not provide source code for everything.

Adding a breakpoint via the dialog to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName` will break, but Visual Studio will say that there is no source code available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some dataAnnotationAttribute for model field, so asp.net takes care about it - before your request fires breakpoint in controller